# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Transform.position'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
public class BABA : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform igrac;
    public Vector3 offset;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Transform.position = igrac.position + offset;
    }
}
```

Comment: probably, you mean to add the offset to the position, so this would be `igrac.position = igrac.position + offset`, or shorter `igrac.position += offset` (as long as the `Transform` type has an operator that takes a `Vector3`)

Comment: `Transform` is the name of a type, `igrac` is an instance of that type (though from the above code it will be null). Read up on static and instance methods. Also make sure you are getting an instance of `Transform` on your behaviour - otherwise you will get a null reference exception (object reference not set to an instance of an object).